# objectify v4 - couldn't import static com.googlecode.objectify.objectifyService.ofy;

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, objectify

- i'm using eclipse
- I added the jar files ( both objectify-4.1-javadoc.jar & guava-16.0.1.jar )
- I added them to the build path

and still this import doesn't work

```
import static com.googlecode.objectify.objectifyService.ofy;
```

**i think it somehow recognizes just the packages.**

( i should probably mention that objectify v3 worked well ,I was just missing a full documentation , if someone could provide one , i'll be very thankful)

Comment: Did you mean 'objectifyService', with a 'c'?

Comment: yes of course , it's just a typing error 
thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The jars are present in the WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: yes , both are present in the WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: Do you have a conflicting objectify.jar on the classpath? Perhaps it's loading the wrong ObjectifyService.

Comment: no, only one objectify jar file.
plus it's not loading any objectify service.
eclipse recogrinzes import com.googlecode.objectify
but it can't find the ObjectifyService in there

Comment: did you add only the javadoc jar without the original jar?

Comment: what is the original jar ?

Comment: thank you , 
i didn't add the "original jar"
i didn't pay attention to this detail 
i feel so stupid now